# Cakephp Link is not recognized in HTML

Tags: html, css, cakephp

I generate in Cakephp with `Html->link` a link

```
echo $this->Html->link('Download',array(
   'plugin'=> 'galleries',
   'controller'=> 'galleries',
   'action'=> 'download',
$download),array('class'=>'down'));
```

The output is

```
<a href="/galleries/galleries/download/schiffchen_seide.jpg" class="down">Download</a>
```

This link is not recognized. I can not click on it.
But if I put the output link and implement it in the HTML code, all is fine

After this I tried to echo the link - same problem.

This is a snippet from my view

```
<nav><a href="#" class="rght">next</a><?php if($download){ echo $this->Html->link('Download',array('plugin' => 'galleries', 'controller' => 'galleries','action' => 'download',  $download),array('class'=>'down')); } ?><a href="#" class="lft">prev</a></nav>
```

Maybe somebody can give me a little hint?

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer to your question and then mark it accepted.

Comment: How do i mark it as accepted?

Comment: After you post your solution (using the form below), click the checkmark that shows up at its left. I think you may have to wait one more day before you can mark it since it's a self-answer.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks for the hint. But i must wait 23 hours to mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:
It was not a PHP Problem but CSS Problem... specially a z-index Problem in my Jquery Plugin (ImageViewer) *rolleyes*
The schemata of the HTML is:

```
<article><div class="info"><nav></nav</div></article><article><div class="info"><nav></nav</div></article><article><div class="info"><nav></nav</div></article>
```

The Problem were the nav tags in every article tag. The "prev&next" links appear in every nav structure but not the "download" link. ergo: i can click on the "prev&next" links but not on the "download" link... So, for a fast solution i set the z-index for my current article view. But i must rework my HTML Code structure

Thanks for reading my question.